# Android json parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing

how to parse only this type of json arrary

```
[{'name':'john', 'age': 44}, {'name':'Alex','age':11}]
```

where i can't do something like this:

```
JSONArray DataListArray = jObject.getJSONArray("???");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the string to initialize the JSON array.

```
String json = "[{'name':'john', 'age': 44}, {'name':'Alex','age':11}]";
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

The string like

```
[{'name':'john', 'age': 44}, {'name':'Alex','age':11}]
```

is **wrong** JSON. You can validate JSON [here](http://www.jsonlint.com/). Correct will be

```
[{"name":"john", "age": 44}, {"name":"Alex","age":11}]
```

Comment: Interesting ,while you are right ,the JSON parser actually did parse it :-)

Comment: @Ravi Vyas: The same was in the old versions of jQuery, but then some old programs don't wirk more. So I strictly recommend you to produce JSON on the server which correspond standards. It will save your time in the future.

Comment: @Ravi Vyas: In general I recommend use any standard functions to serialize an object to JSON string instead of manual serialization. Such standard functions depend on the server technology used, but it produce valid JSON. For example if the string has " (double quote) or \ (backslash) inside the characters **must** be escaped (like \" and \\). Typical error in manual serialization is that one don't do this. So the usage of any standard functions which convert object to JSON is really strict recommended.